# UFO map in Lil' Probe Inn indicates real points of interest?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I went to Lil' Probe Inn and in the office behind the counter there was a map of the game with marked points on it, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Does anyone know if these points reveal something in the san andreas world?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Nice first question. I haven't played this game in forever. Is one of those dots on Area 51?

Comment: @DCShannon the 4th one (left to right, top to bottom) looks like it is. And it's called Area 69, just another one of them sexual innuendoes in GTA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a total of 7 marks on the map.

- The northernmost dot on the map seems to point out the location of
  the Desert Building.
- Another dot marks the location of Area 69. The next dot seemingly
  points to the Big Ear.
- The following dot points to a large unused       warehouse building
  in Las Venturas, just north of the Greenglass       College.
- The next    dot is in the exact center of the map, in
  Blueberry, Los    Santos.
- The dot below it is placed just east of    the      Easter Bay
  Chemical Plant.
- The final and southernmost dot    is       strangely     placed in
  the middle of the junction between    Sasquatch       Creek    and
  its western fork, in Shady Creeks.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but are there any "easter egg" about aliens, in the places marked in the map?

Comment: No there are no signs of aliens on the Map.